# Git push fails when modified files are included in push, but succeeds when added or deleted files

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu-10.10

I've been using git for a few months and have never run into problems.  I met my match today.  I have a system running Ubuntu 10.10 (new system).  I put my keys in place to access the server, and can ssh in just fine.  I cloned my repos just fine.  I can push added / deleted files just fine.  However, when I try to push modified files, the push doesn't finish.  It hangs on the last line (Starts with "Total")

If I wait 15 minutes or so it gives me these errors:

Write failed: Broken pipe
Fatal: The remote host hung up unexpectedly

I've tried pushing as both regular user and sudo user.  When I add a verbose flag to the push, nothing.

I think this is an SSH error, but it is completely puzzling me.  Can anyone help?

Comment: It looks to me like the problem is somewhere on the server end.

Comment: Is this server under your control? Is it just a plain ol' repository? Gitolite? GitHub? Does it potentially have hooks?

Comment: Server is under my control.  I can push from other machines just fine.

Comment: It's a plain old git repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just going to run a list of ideas here.

Is this plain SSH or are you using e.g. -o ProxyCommand or another tunnel of sorts?

---

- I'd check the version of the client, since you report being able to do the same correctly from other machines.
- I'd also try creating a bundle from the client to eliminate the transport from the analysis.
- I'd check file permissions (and out-of-space/quota/temp space for the user) on the server. Are you using the same user that works for other clients?
- You could look at a problem in the garbage collect step on the server (by using git config to make sure it doesn't happen).
- Did you try other protocols (git-daemon or smart http server?)
- Could something be up locally (like repository on synch NFS, or dropbox or...)?

Comment: Good tips.  I purged and then reinstalled git, and found a version that worked.  Thanks for the help = )